# How can I show a cradled FAB in a bottom app bar for only one particular fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, material-ui

I'm using a BottomAppBar in my app and I need to show a cradled FloatingActionButton for only one particular fragment. I don't want the button to be shown in other fragments.

My activity_main.xml has a Frame (for displaying the other fragments) and a BottomAppBar:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/backgroundSecondary"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/round_menu_24" />
```

In MainActivity.java has this code to set the BottomAppBar:

```
navBar = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);
setSupportActionBar(navBar);
```

I'm using a BottomSheetDialogFragment to handle navigation between fragments in the app.
How can I change the BottomAppBar to contain a FAB when a particular fragment is launched?

Comment: Did you try with `fab.show()/fab.hide()` in your activity before launching specific fragment?

Comment: I'm handling the launching of fragments in a bottom sheet fragment, so I can't call those methods in its class

Comment: Try using callback from `bottom sheet fragment` to `Activity`

Comment: You are welcome @Aryan. Added as answer, Please accept and upvote so that others can find it helpful .Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using callback from `bottom sheet fragment` to `Activity`

And then inside callback try to show / hide the fab in your activity like below:

```
fab.show() //To show fab
fab.hide() // To hide fab
```